# FirebaseAppDistribution: Missing app id in the appDistributionUpload gradle command

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-app-distribution

I am using the Firebase App Distribution with the Gradle plugin.
When I try to run the `appDistributionUploadDebug` command I receive the error:

```
Getting appId from output of google services plugin

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:appDistributionUploadDebug'.
> Missing app id
```

I included the plugin in the `build.gradle` file

```
   dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appdistribution-gradle:1.2.0'
    }
```

Then I added the config:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.appdistribution'

android {
   //...
        debug {
            firebaseAppDistribution {
                serviceAccountCredentials = "/path/to/your-service-account-key.json"
                releaseNotesFile="/path/to/releasenotes.txt"
                testers="email@example.com"
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are **not using** the google services gradle plugin in your project you **have to add** the **`appId`** property in your [configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/distribute-gradle#3_configure_your_distribution_properties).

Something like:

```
            firebaseAppDistribution {
                // Firebase App Distribution setup
                appId = "...."  //<-- add your appID

                serviceAccountCredentials = "/path/to/your-service-account-key.json"
                releaseNotesFile="/path/to/releasenotes.txt"
                testers="email@example.com"
            }
```

You can find the `appId` value in the `google-services.json` file

```
{
  ...
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "...",//<-- YOU NEED THIS APP_ID
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "..."
        }
      },
     
  ...
}
```

or in the Firebase console on the Project Settings page -> General Tab.

Comment: I'm using latest google services and firebase app distribution gradle plugin, and have verified that my appId is present in the play services json, for my entire matrix of build type and flavor, and yet I get `Cannot query the value of task ':project:appDistributionUploadDevDebug' property 'appId' because it has no value available.`

Answer (score 0):

If you have **multiple apps** under the same **firebase project**, then you need to specify **appId** directly in gradle file - which app should be picked for uploading.

```
firebaseAppDistribution {
    appId = "from google-service.json file"

    serviceCredentialsFile = "..."
    artifactType = "APK"
    releaseNotesFile = "..."
    groups = "..."
}
```

Your **google-services.json** file

```
{
  ...
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        ...
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "app #1" // this is your app id
        ...
      }
    },
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "app #2" // this is your app id
      }
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

### [Distribute Android apps to testers using Gradle](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/distribute-gradle)

*Output error on appDistributionVersion 2.0.0:*

> Could not find the APK. Make sure you build first by running ./gradlew
> assemble[Variant]

---

So that the APK can be found, make sure you build **first** by running `./gradlew assemble[Variant]` and **then** `./gradlew appDistributionUpload[Variant]`.

```
$ ./gradlew assemble[Variant] appDistributionUpload[Variant]
```